# How to run maven job on UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, maven

I created J-Meter tests and I run them using maven, On Windows, I run maven executing batch command `mvn -Ppolar clean test` from command prompt in folder where pom.xml file is placed.

I have a problem now because we should run tests on UNIX and I don't know how to run maven on UNIX. Does anybody know what should be equivalent command for `mvn -Ppolar clean test` on UNIX?

Thanks

Comment: Run the very same command you run in Win.

Comment: Plus add the maven binary to your PATH

Answer (score 3):

It's exactly the same as in Windows.

Have you installed the Maven linux package from "http://maven.apache.org/download.html"?

Answer (score 1):

Maven is cross platform because it is written in Java. So if everything is configured properly, you should run exactly the same command line as in Windows.